# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 drivers for Nvidia Geforce 820M

Tags: 16.04, drivers, apt, nvidia, graphics

I have a Lenovo Z50-70 laptop, which has Intel Integrated Graphics and an Nvidia Geforce 820M; however, since I installed Ubuntu 16.04, it has not been using the graphics card. I have tried uninstalling everything Nvidia-related and reinstalling `nvidia-375`, which then declares that it depends on `libc6-i386`, which then returns

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu3) but 2.23-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try to install `libc6`, I get `libc6 is already the newest version (2.23-0ubuntu5).`

How do I install these, or is there another way to make my graphics card work?

In terms of other commands:

`lspci -vnn | grep 3D -A 12` returns:

```
03:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] [10de:1140] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Lenovo GeForce 820M [17aa:380d]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
Memory at c2000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]
Expansion ROM at <ignored> [disabled]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list` returns:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe
```

Comment: Have You disabled the integrated intel graphics in BIOS ?

Comment: So the adapter is seen. Driver is not installed.

Comment: @Pilot6 I get that, but I can't install it.

Comment: Do you have any PPA added? The current version of `libc6-i386` is `2.23-0ubuntu7`. It looks like you install not from the official repos.

Comment: Update your system by `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: @Pilot6 Here is my [`/etc/apt/sources.list.d`](https://pastebin.com/iTZ5h3Mi); would `graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list` be the one causing problems?

Comment: The PPA may reqire wrong dependencies.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've removed `bumblebee` and `graphics-drivers`, but I still have the same issues.

Comment: Did you update your system?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57823/discussion-between-benedict-randall-shaw-and-pilot6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The Nvidia adapter will be seen if you instead of `grep VGA` will use `grep 3D`.
2. `nvidia-340` is wrong for this adapter. Install `nvidia-375`.

You have only `main` and `universe` repos connected. Go to System Settings -> Software & Updates and enable all other repos, especially `restricted`. `xenial-updates` is not connected either. You need to enable it as well.

You may need to update the system before you install the driver.

Comment: Have done all of those, but I still can't install `libc6-i386`, for some reason beyond my understanding.

Comment: @BenedictRandallShaw Remove ANY PPA you may have added. That's the problem. Then follow the instructions above. Do **not** install `nvidia-current`.

Comment: Which instructions? I have removed all PPAs, then added `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` back to allow install of `nvidia-375`, but I still have issues with `libc6-i386`.

Comment: You do not need `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` to install `nvidia-375` on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I have run `ppa-purge ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`, then `apt-get update`, and `apt-get install nvidia-375` gives `E: Unable to locate package nvidia-375`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ought I to try installing a `.deb` file from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-375)?

Comment: Something is wrong with your repos. Please post the output of  `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` TO YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have done so.

Comment: I added to my answer.